# What's wrong while saving Python QTableWidget data into EXCEL

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python scripting and now is trying to design a window interface to save daily expense into EXCEL file.
I have written a QTableWidget to type in the daily expense information but found the error message "AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'tableWidget'" while saving the data into EXCEL file.
Can anyone give me the hint to move forward?

Below is my code for your reference.

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):                              #Initial a Window frame
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.labels()                                #insert labels
        self.buttons()                               #insert buttons
        self.draglists()
        self.table()
.
.
.

    def table(self):
        table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        table.setRowCount(20)
        table.setColumnCount(4)
        table.resize(450, 300)
        table.move(640, 100)
        horHeader = ['Date', 'Category', 'Item', 'Expense']
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeader)
    def savefile(self):
        filename = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))
        wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
        sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        self.add2(sheet)
        wbk.save(filename)

    def add2(self, sheet):
        for currentColumn in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
            for currentRow in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                try:
                    teext = str(self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, currentColumn)).text()
                    sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, teext)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.setGeometry (50, 50, 1200, 600)
    ex.show()
    ex.setWindowTitle("Search Engine for Expense")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing something you haven't defined yet.  Your class `Window` inherits from `QtGui.QWidget`, which doesn't have an attribute called `tableWidget`, yet you reference an attribute called `tableWidget` here:

```
def add2(self, sheet):
        for currentColumn in range(self.**tableWidget**.columnCount()):
            for currentRow in range(self.**tableWidget**.rowCount()):
                try:
                    teext = str(self.**tableWidget**.item(currentRow, currentColumn)).text()
                    sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, teext)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
```

Hence the error.  If you want `self.tableWidget` to reference the table you made in `table(self)`, you'd need to make it an instance attribute at the end of the function like so:

```
def table(self):
    table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
    table.setRowCount(20)
    table.setColumnCount(4)
    table.resize(450, 300)
    table.move(640, 100)
    horHeader = ['Date', 'Category', 'Item', 'Expense']
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeader)
    self.tableWidget = table
```

That will allow your other functions to access the table and its attributes, including `.columnCount()` and `.rowCount()`.

Hope that helps.